# How (if at all) can I mock a mocked class on the heap?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I created a test mock class pretty much as simple as described in the docs:

```
class MockLogicLoopable : public LogicLoopable 
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(update,void());
  MOCK_METHOD0(loopableType,LoopableType());
};
```

Now I'd like to do something like this:

```
TEST(Examplegroup,Example)
{
    MockLogicLoopable* mll = new MockLogicLoopable();
    EXPECT_CALL(mll,loopableType())
        .WillRepeatedly(Return(LOGIC));
}
```

I'm not really sure how, if at all, something like this can be realized with googlemock.

Comment: And what mocking library do you use!?

Comment: Google Mock, clearly, @Storyteller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a pointer in `mll`, but `EXPECT_CALL` expects its first argument to be a value. Dereference your pointer with `*`, just as you would any other:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mll, loopableType())
  .WillRepeatedly(Return(LOGIC));
```